# Show that $S^1$ acts on $S^3$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, topological-groups, group-actions

$S^3=\{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C^2} \mid |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1 \}$

> Show that $S^1$ acts on  $S^3$ by $z \cdot (z_1, z_2)=(zz_1, zz_2)$

---

An action of a topological group $G$ on a topological space $X$ (by homeomorphisms) is a continuous map $F : G \times X \rightarrow X$ such that the following $3$ conditions hold:

1. For each fixed $g \in G$ the map $F(g, \cdot) : X \rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism
2. The identity element acts as identity map
3. Product is respected: $F(gh, a)=F(g, F(h, a))$

So in this case, I think $G=S^1$ and $X=S^3$

1. Is $z \cdot (z_1, z_2)=(zz_1, zz_2)$ a homeomorphism? I believe it is due to continuity and bijectivity... but I do not know about an inverse? Could someone help me with that?
2. $e \in S^1$ gives $e \cdot (z_1, z_2)=(ez_1, ez_2)$ so I think this works...
3. And products seem to be respected

---

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding these criteria, if someone could help me outline this in more detail that would be great

Comment: The inverse of $F(z,\cdot)$ is $F(\overline  z, \cdot)$. Furthermore, the identity of $S^1$ is simply $1$ and multiplication is continuous. Your are also right about $G$ and $X$.

Comment: Thanks.. Why is it so that the conjugate is the inverse?

Comment: If $z \in S^1$ then it is true that $z \overline z = 1$ since for any complex number we have that $z \overline z = \lvert z  \rvert ^2$.

Comment: of course I see now.. thank you!

Comment: @Epsilon Using $\bar z$ for $z^{-1}$ obscures the fact that if $z$ acts by an automorphism, then its inverse must be the automorphism by which $z^{-1}$ acts.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't understand. What do you think the inverse is?